# Guest customization with ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have already opened a issue for pyvmomi (https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/issues/312), but no answer so far.

Basically what I want to do is run the Guest customization after I have deployed a OVF to the ESXi.
On a vCenter server, this is working as expected. But it is failing on ESXi

I guess the main question is, if Guest customization is working or not on a single ESXi server.

If anyone can answer this, or even better, has experience with using PowerCLI or PyVmomi to do this with ESXi.

I'm out of ideas.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Using [PowerCli built-in](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2014/09/powercli-5-8-new-feature-get-ovfconfiguration-part-1-2.html) CmdLet `Import-vApp` could help you a lot. However, it needs to connect to a vCenter server, not an ESXi host. So, no donut for you

However, if you look at the [VirtuallyGhetto](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/05/how-to-deploy-ovfova-in-esxi-shell.html) blog, you will find tips to another tool that is suitable for your needs: `ovftool`. It is a [Vmware](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/) command-line utility that allows you to import and export OVF packages from Vmware products. You could even host the ovf file on a http mirror or directly download if from the internet to deploy your machines as the example from the blog:

```
/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/vmware-ovftool/ovftool -dm=thin -ds=datastore1 "--net:access333=VM Network" "http://air.primp-industries.com/SLES-VM/SLES-VM.ovf" "vi://root:vmware123@172.30.0.192"
```

**Means**: Deploy this ovf with thin provisioning, on datastore datastore1, map the net name  access33 from the ovf to VM Network, get the ovf from this http server, and this is the server, use these credentials on host(ESXi).

**Disclaimer:** It works on ESXi but it is not officially supported by VMware. It´s a workaround to use `ovftool` directly inside the ESXi host. That is the reason why, for example, you have to type your password on the last field because if you dont, it will print a loop of `*` on your screen.

**Related documentation**: OVFTool vmware [doc](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf410/ovftool-410_userguide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. But I have no issue with the deployment of the VM. I already use OVA files as there is no clone or anything. But I need a means of doing the same customisation I already do for normal vCenter clones.

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what you want? You need to customize  the vm AFTER you deploy an OVA, or a third part feature that is simmilar to Clone on ESXi?